# Why is this not calling a function every second?

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Why is this not drawing a circle every second, a circle randomly positiioned and increasing in radius?

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>
<script>
var count = 0;
 function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
  function draw() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(getRandomInt(400), getRandomInt(400), 5*count++, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  setTimeout(draw,1000);
}
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Shane

Comment: I made you a snippet to demonstrate the problem. You've got a console error because your JS code refers to an undeclared variable.

Comment: Use your developer tools in the browser!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your forgot to initialize 'count'. See the snipet.

```js
  var count = 0

function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}
  function draw() {
  var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(getRandomInt(400), getRandomInt(400), 5*count++, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = "green";
  ctx.fill();
  }
  setInterval(draw,1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;">
</canvas>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes I accidentally deleted it. All working now.

Answer (score 0):

?### You did not defined count variable

I added `count` variable above `getRandomInt` function

```
var count = 0;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="400" style="border: 1px solid #000000"> </canvas>
    <script>
      var count = 0;
      function getRandomInt(max) {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
      }
      function draw() {
        console.log("Hello");
        var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(getRandomInt(400), getRandomInt(400), 5 * count++, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fillStyle = "green";
        ctx.fill();
      }
      setInterval(draw, 1000);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've updated the question. Again why is it not calling the draw function every second Instead it is drawing all the circles simultaneously.

Comment: it should. Let me recheck